# Selecting words having a specific number of letters from a text

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to select all the words in a text that have a specific number of letters. This is the way I am doing it now.

```
text = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google"];

nletters = 15;

Select[StringCases[text, LetterCharacter ..], StringLength @ # == nletters &]
```

Is there any way to do it using only string patterns?

Comment: Can you give us an example of text that doesn't require us to import from the web? You are more likely to get an answer if you edit your question to replace the `Import` with an actual string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression. For example:

```
StringCases[
    ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}],
    RegularExpression["\\b[a-zA-Z]{15}\\b"]
]
```

> {"undistinguished", "Representatives"}

Answer (score 5):

```
StringCases[text, WordBoundary ~~ Repeated[LetterCharacter, {15}] ~~ WordBoundary]
```

> {"discontinuation", "Internationally", "InformationWeek",     "Anticompetitive", "InformationWeek", "Environmentally",     "Transliteration", "InterActiveCorp"}

```
StringCases[text,  WordBoundary ~~ x : LetterCharacter .. ~~ WordBoundary /; 
  StringLength[x] == 15]
```

> {"discontinuation", "Internationally", "InformationWeek",     "Anticompetitive", "InformationWeek", "Environmentally",     "Transliteration", "InterActiveCorp"}